# binding entity to datagridview and allow editing and deleting

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I want to bind a linq query to it.

This is at my class level:

```
   private readonly SuburbanPortalEntities _entities;
   private List<PaymentType> _paymentTypes;
```

Here is the code in my load:

```
  _paymentTypes = (from pt in _entities.PaymentTypes
            where pt.CorporationId.Equals(_currentcorp.CorporationId)
            select pt).ToList();
  dataGridView_PaymentTypes.DataSource = _paymentTypes;
```

And this is my insert, which at this point, does nothing at all:

```
private void button_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var row = new PaymentType();
  row.IsActive = false;
  row.IsAdded = true;
  row.CorporationId = _currentcorp.CorporationId;
  row.TokenId = _token.TokenId;
  row.PaymentTypeId = Guid.NewGuid();
  row.ExcludeCreditCodes = 9;
  _paymentTypes.Add(row);
}
```

And my simple save button:

```
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

It is working on existing records. When I make changes to them, it changes the data in the database. It isn't working for the new records and I don't have a delete since I'm not sure how to do it.

I'd prefer to allow the datagridview to add the record on the row instead of a button. Also, with the deletes, allow the datagridview to handle the delete.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for insert new data into sql server, you can try this:

```
private void button_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var row = new PaymentType();
  row.IsActive = false;
  row.IsAdded = true;
  row.CorporationId = _currentcorp.CorporationId;
  row.TokenId = _token.TokenId;
  row.PaymentTypeId = Guid.NewGuid();
  row.ExcludeCreditCodes = 9;
  _entities.PaymentTypes.Add(row);  //for linq to sql, you should use InsertOnSubmit()
  _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```